flutter video fails to render on some devices on android
am using a video player in Flutter app and it works great on most devices,,but on some other mobiles it fails to load with the following error :
PlatformExcepetion ( videoerror:video player had error v0.n: MediaCodecVideoRenderrer error , index=0 , format=Format(1,null,null,video/avs,avc1.64001E,-1,null[352,640,25.000673,Colorinfo(BT709,Limited range , SDR SMTPE 170M , false,8bit Luma , 8bit Chrome)],[-1,1]),format_supported=YES,null,null)

here is my code snippet :
// Automatic FlutterFlow imports
import '/backend/backend.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/custom_code/widgets/index.dart'; // Imports other custom widgets
import '/custom_code/actions/index.dart'; // Imports custom actions
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom widget code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

import '/custom_code/widgets/index.dart';
import '/custom_code/actions/index.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart';

import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:wakelock_plus/wakelock_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class CustomVideoPlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomVideoPlayer({
    super.key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    required this.videoURL,
  });

  final double? width;
  final double? height;
  final String videoURL;

  @override
  State<CustomVideoPlayer> createState() => _CustomVideoPlayerState();
}

class _CustomVideoPlayerState extends State<CustomVideoPlayer> {
  late VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController;
  ChewieController? chewieController;
  bool isLoading = true;
  String? errorMessage;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializePlayer();
  }

  Future<bool> _checkVideoFormat() async {
    // Check if the URL has a supported video format
    final supportedFormats = ['.mp4', '.m3u8', '.webm'];
    final lowercaseUrl = widget.videoURL.toLowerCase();
    return supportedFormats.any((format) => lowercaseUrl.contains(format));
  }

  Future<void> _initializePlayer() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
      errorMessage = null;
    });

    try {
      if (!await _checkVideoFormat()) {
        throw Exception(
            'Unsupported video format. Please use MP4, HLS, or WebM.');
      }

      videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(
        Uri.parse(widget.videoURL),
      );

      bool initialized = false;
      await Future.wait([
        videoPlayerController.initialize().then((_) => initialized = true),
        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 15)),
      ]).timeout(
        const Duration(seconds: 15),
        onTimeout: () {
          if (!initialized) {
            throw Exception(
                'Video loading timed out. Please check your internet connection.');
          }
          return [];
        },
      );

      chewieController = ChewieController(
        videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
        autoPlay: true,
        looping: true,
        aspectRatio: videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
        allowedScreenSleep: false,
        allowFullScreen: true,
        deviceOrientationsAfterFullScreen: [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp],
        placeholder: Container(
          color: Colors.black,
          child: const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        errorBuilder: (context, errorMessage) {
          return Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.error_outline, color: Colors.red, size: 32),
                  SizedBox(height: 8),
                  Text(
                    errorMessage,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 16),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: _retryInitialization,
                    child: Text('Retry'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );

      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error initializing video player: $e');
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
          errorMessage = e.toString();
        });
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> _retryInitialization() async {
    // Cleanup existing controllers
    videoPlayerController.dispose();
    chewieController?.dispose();

    // Reinitialize
    await _initializePlayer();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (isLoading) {
      return Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            CircularProgressIndicator(),
            SizedBox(height: 16),
            Text('Loading video...'),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }

    if (errorMessage != null || chewieController == null) {
      return Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.error_outline, color: Colors.red, size: 32),
              SizedBox(height: 8),
              Text(
                errorMessage ?? 'Error loading video',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 16),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: _retryInitialization,
                child: Text('Retry'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    WakelockPlus.enable();
    return Container(
      width: widget.width,
      height: widget.height,
      child: Chewie(
        controller: chewieController!,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    videoPlayerController.dispose();
    chewieController?.dispose();
    WakelockPlus.disable();
    super.dispose();
  }
}


